# Insert image from flutter to database with .net core

Tags: flutter, dart, asp.net-core-webapi, imagepicker

I generate an ASP.NET Core Web API to insert the feedback and image:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("feedback")]
    public IActionResult InsertFeedback ([FromBody] FAQModel dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var addFeedback = new FAQFeedback();
            addFeedback.name = dto.name;
            addFeedback.feedback = dto.feedback;
            addFeedback.status = "WIP";
            addFeedback.createdDate = DateTime.Now;

            context.FAQFeedback.Add(addFeedback);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Image/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(int id, IFormFile image)
    {
        try
        {
            string path;
            var fb = context.FAQFeedback.Where(d => d.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            string uploadFolder = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/{imageFolder}";

            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

            path = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, id + ".png");

            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            string savedPath = $"{_baseURL}{imageFolder}/{id}.png";
            fb.image = savedPath;
            context.FAQFeedback.Update(fb);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(fb);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I create this future function in my model class

```
  Future<bool> addFeedback (
      String name, String feedback) async {
    final body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'feedback': feedback
    });
    var response = await httpSer.post('faq/feedback', body,);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is how I create feedback form to display in screen, and upload the image and submit the feedback to database, but I'm having the problem to upload the image to database.

```
class _FAQFeedbackState extends State<FAQFeedback> {
  File? _image; // Variable to store the selected image
  TextEditingController feedbackText = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameText = TextEditingController();
  ShowDialog dx = ShowDialog();
  late bool isSubmit;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSubmit = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameText.dispose();
    feedbackText.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  disableButton() {
    setState(() {
      isSubmit = true;
    });
  }

  enableButton() {
    setState(() {
      isSubmit = false;
    });
  }

  Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (pickedFile == null) return;

      final imageTemporary = File(pickedFile.path);

      setState(() {
        this._image = imageTemporary;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  submitFeedback() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      disableButton();
      final name = nameText.text;
      final feedback = feedbackText.text;
      //final image = _image?.path;

      bool response = await Provider.of<FAQProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addFeedback(name, feedback);

      if (response) {
        dx.showSuccessMsg(context, "Completed", "Thanks for your feedback");
      } else {
        dx.errorAlert(context, "Invalid.");
        enableButton();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'Feedback',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.h,
              color: customPrimarySwatch.shade50,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.h),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                feedbackForm(size),
                SizedBox(height: 20.h),
                uploadImage(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.h),
                submitButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget feedbackForm(Size size) {
    return Container(
      height: 300.h,
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              enabled: !isSubmit,
              controller: nameText,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Name",
                hintText: "Name",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffe5e5e5)),
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Name is required.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 12
                    .h), // Add spacing between the name field and the feedback field
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                enabled: !isSubmit,
                controller: feedbackText,
                expands: true,
                maxLength: 5000,
                maxLines: null,
                minLines: null,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your feedback';
                  }
                  return null; //Return null if the input is valid
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Feedback",
                  hintText: "Please briefly describe the issue.",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13.h,
                    color: Color(0xffc5c5c5),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffe5e5e5)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget uploadImage() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<ImageSource>(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<ImageSource>>[
            PopupMenuItem<ImageSource>(
              value: ImageSource.gallery,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.photo_album_rounded),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.h),
                  Text('Photo Library'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            PopupMenuItem<ImageSource>(
              value: ImageSource.camera,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.h),
                  Text('Take Photo'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffe5e5e5),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.h),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.h),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.upload_rounded,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.h),
                  Text(
                    "Upload Image",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 14.h,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onSelected: (ImageSource source) => getImage(source),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            height: 10.h), // Add spacing between the button and the file name
        if (_image != null)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.network(
                //to show image, you type like this.
                _image!.path,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        SizedBox(
            height: 10.h), // Add spacing between the image and the file name
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget submitButton() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 35.h,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: isSubmit ? null : submitFeedback,
        child: isSubmit
            ? const SpinKitCircle(
                color: primaryColor,
                size: 20.0,
              )
            : const Text(txtSubmit),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The data of name, feedback and image is share with same table in database. Any help to solve the problem?